# Flutter - How to add two Text Widgets in a Column with the 2nd one overflowing vertically after filling the spaces horizontally?

Tags: dart, flutter

I made a Chat app, I made two Text widgets inside a Column widget, now I want to make the **Chat message (the 2nd text Widget) Text Widget to go Vertically after filling the spaces horizontally**, so what can I do, this is the [image of the Chat screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78AA1.png)
and What happens is [this(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2JhK.png), the images are embedded because I'm a new user

The Code of it is this:-

```
 Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[

          /// USER NAME
          Text(userName, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle),


          /// CHAT MESSAGE
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
            child: Text(
              theText,
              maxLines: null,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body2,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

I expected the Code to work like the traditional Chat app's messages, **the First text widget (USERNAME) worked but the 2nd one (the actual CHAT MESSAGE) didn't work as it Overflows** by pixels, So how can I fix this and **Make it like the traditional Chat Messages**??

Comment: Try to use Wrap instead of Column.

Comment: No, if I use a wrap I can't assign the crossAxisAlignment, instead, I used Flexible as a parent of Column and it resolved my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I resolved the problem!** And here it is:

I just wrapped my whole `Column` widget with a **Flexible widget** and it resolved my problem and now I can add `Multiline Messages`!

[image: The Image]

**I'm keeping the post as to any Newbie facing the same problem 'may' find this useful...**